# Генератор валидного ИНН

Tags: python, python-3.x

Генерить Валидный inn: Нашел в инете вот такой код, но вообще не понимаю Где здесь генерится конечный inn. Подскажите:

```
def inn_ctrl_summ(nums, type):
    """
    Подсчет контрольной суммы
    """
    inn_ctrl_type = {
        'n2_12': [7, 2, 4, 10, 3, 5, 9, 4, 6, 8],
        'n1_12': [3, 7, 2, 4, 10, 3, 5, 9, 4, 6, 8],
        'n1_10': [2, 4, 10, 3, 5, 9, 4, 6, 8],
    }
    n = 0
    l = inn_ctrl_type[type]
    for i in range(0, len(l)):
        n += nums[i] * l[i]
    return n % 11 % 10

def inn_gen(l=None):
    """
    Генерация ИНН (10 или 12 значный)
    На входе указывается длина номера - 10 или 12.
    Если ничего не указано, будет выбрана случайная длина.
    """
    if not l:
        l = list((10, 12))[rnd(0, 1)]
    if l not in (10, 12):
        return None
    nums = [
        rnd(1, 9) if x == 0
        else rnd(0, 9)
        for x in range(0, 9 if l == 10 else 10)
    ]
    if l == 12:
        n2 = inn_ctrl_summ(nums, 'n2_12')
        nums.append(n2)
        n1 = inn_ctrl_summ(nums, 'n1_12')
        nums.append(n1)
    elif l == 10:
        n1 = inn_ctrl_summ(nums, 'n1_10')
        nums.append(n1)
    return ''.join([str(x) for x in nums])
```

Comment: че такое `inn` ?

Comment: @Victor VosMottor ИНН - Идентификационный номер налогоплательщика

Comment: криминалом не занимаюсь ;)

Comment: так вот ведь функция генерирует `def inn_gen(l=None)`

Comment: В комментарии написано же.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor если нужно нагенерировать кучу фиктивных физлиц с правдоподобными ФИО, ИНН, телефонами для тестирования какого-то сервиса - это криминал?

Comment: @insolor А я понятия не имею для чего ему это надо. Тем более, что если человек задает такой вопрос, то ему тестировать вряд ли есть чего.

Comment: @insolor Да и вообще это шутка про криминал ;)

Comment: @insolor Все верно. Это автотест, который проверяет успешную работу сервиса, а там стоит проверка на уникальный номер телефона и уникальный валидный ИНН)))

Answer (score 2):

Вот тут ИНН:

```
print(''.join([str(x) for x in nums]))
```

Всем большое спасибо за помощь